# Is it possible to change the Finish button text for mobile?

Tags: docusignapi

When a signer is signing an envelope, the text for the Finish button seems to be configurable for the desktop experience, through modifying the 'DocuSign_FinishSigning' setting in the signing resources XML file.  However, changing this setting seems to have no effect on the mobile signing experience.  Is there a way to change the text of the finish button for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

From previous examples I've used the **DocuSign_SignerPlacedComplete** element in the signing resource file to customize this text on mobile.